# Medication administration in MIMIC-III

Tags: mimic-iii

Does MIMIC-III provide any medication administration data for oral or IV push medications?  I'm aware that the PRESCRIPTIONS table contains all medications, but this table only reflects ordered medications (not the MAR).

For example, if I want to identify patients who received IV push enalaprilat, I can see 788 entries of 'enalaprilat' in the PRESCRIPTIONS table:

```
select count(*) from prescriptions where drug ilike 'enalaprilat'
-- Returns 788 entries
```

But because I cannot identify a D_ITEM corresponding to enalaprilat, there will not be any entries in the INPUTEVENTS tables:

```
select * from d_items where label ilike 'enalaprilat'
-- This query does not return any rows
```

I assume that IV push and oral medications are not considered as "input" because they are small or negligible volumes.  Is there any MAR equivalent in MIMIC to verify that a prescription/order was actually given to a patient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An electronic MAR is is fairly new and thus is not available in the data set:

> https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/issues/292
>
> The electronic medication administration record (eMAR) went online
>   only a few years ago and so is not in MIMIC-III v1.4. We plan to add
>   on something similar for a subset of patients in a future update. Stay
>   tuned! :)